# How can I avoid vote spam on my PHP site

Tags: php

I am doing a voting system on my website.

Visitors do not need to login to vote the product they like. But how can I prevent them from clicking the like or dislike button many times for one product ?

I intend to detect the IP address of the visitor to avoid vote spam. Is that a good way?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: without login, ip address is about the only way.  Even thats not full proof given proxies

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a very answerable question. What am I missing?

Comment: There is no way to stop the same person from voting over and over again, it is bad programming by design. There are many ways to make sure the 'average' user doesn't keep voting, but you shouldn't program things for the 'average' user..

Comment: @donutdan4114 He said avoid, not prevent. Cut him some slack.

Comment: @MikeB - Yea, but it only takes one person, one time, to screw up the vote counts for every item.. It's just not a good way of thinking about things.

Comment: @donutdan4114 Doesn't stop sites like espn.com, newegg.com, and cnn.com from posting public polls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not a good way. IP can be common via proxy - colleges and large businesses for example.

You could store a cookie, but that can easily be circumvented.

The concise answer is that controlled voting should probably be handled through a login handler and not just wide open to the public. But if you do want to leave it wide open to the public, then you have to accept the flood of badness that may come with that decision.

I would go with at least cookies. Not a whole lot of people care to clear cookies just to game a voting system unless there is a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Create database table for logging users. Colums will look like that

```
ID | IP  | Browser
```

ID will be auto-increment value

Get IP with following function (of course it's not 100% reliable way. )

```
 function getIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { //check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { //to check ip is pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
        return $ip;
}
```

And browser with Javascript. You can post it to php side via ajax. (We're doing this to increase reliability of detection.)

Then check this table everytime when user tries to vote. You can search for browser and ip. If num_rows>0 then prevent (notify visitor) voting.

Answer (score 1):

if not login/IP, may be have a cookie and set it when they vote.

Comment: yes, i will use cookie instead of IP, thank you for help